# Why the small number string is greater than big number string

Tags: javascript, typescript

When the smaller number string when compared with the larger number string - the result is `true`.

How is it possible?

```js
document.write(`Why the result of '2'>'10' is ${'2'>'10'}`)
```

Any expert here?

Comment: You can try `document.write("Why the result of '2'>'10' is ${'02'>'10'}")`  to see what you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings, so a lexical comparison is performed instead of a numerical comparison.

Lexically, `2` comes after `1`.

Comment: Super duper dupe!!!

Comment: I'm reading about it to understand what you said